# I don't follow the math happening in this script

Tags: windows, batch-file, math, for-loop, time

I know that these loops are for the purpose of converting a time variable into I think milliseconds. 
Could someone help me decypher the math and have the loop convert to minutes instead?

```
    for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!start!") do (
        set /a "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
    )       

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!end!") do (
        set /a "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
    )
```

I guess to be more specific, I don't understand where the `%%b %%c` and `%%d` came from or the "rogue" `%%` are doing. I dont understand why the variables are being multiplied by 60+1 or 100+1. I'm guessing that theyre either being multiplied by 60 or 100 based on if it converting between hours -> minutes or seconds -> centiseconds. Did I even follow that correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the initial %%a `for` token is specified, the `"tokens=1-4"` options indicates that there will be four tokens used total, so the for loop sets aside %%a, %%b, %%c, and %%d for use within that loop. Since `!start!` is something in the format HH:MM:SS.cc, %%a is HH, %%b is MM, %%c is SS, and %%d is cc.

`%%` is a math operator used to return the modulus of two numbers. (Remember when you first learned division and you got a remainder instead of a decimal? The modulus is the remainder.)

The 1 is a way to ensure that numbers don't start with 0, because batch considers numbers that start with 0 to be octal, so 08 and 09 are not valid numbers according to batch, which will break things. Since %% trumps + in order of operations, the math is actually (1%%b %% 100). This takes advantage of the fact that batch lets you create variables out of other concatenated strings. Say %%b is 05. 1%%b %% 100 becomes 105 %% 100, which is just 5.

To convert the time to minutes instead of centiseconds, change the equations from

```
(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100
```

to

```
(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)
```

If you want decimal parts to the minute value and have PowerShell installed, you can add the lines

```
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('powershell !start!/6000') do set start=%%A
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('powershell !end!/60000') do set end=%%A
```

which will return string representations of decimal numbers. Because powershell returns values that go to 11 decimal places, you may want to use a [substring](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.MidString) to remove any extra digits you don't want.

Comment: But this only gives me rounded minutes.

Comment: Batch isn't capable of non-integer math. Also, you never specified that you wanted non-whole minutes.

Comment: I apologize, is there a way then to use magic to get float results?

Comment: @David, if you have powershell installed, I've added code that will return a string representation of the decimal value you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!start!") do (
    set /a "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)
```

**Translated:**

`tokens=1-4` means that there will be four variables (`a,b,c,d`) created out of the input based upon the delimiters `:.,`  The variables are expanded using the `%%X` notation.  When you see just `%%` that means just a literal percent sign `%` (aka the modulus operator in math).

- Token 1 = A
- Token 2 = B
- Token 3 = C
- Token 4 = D

**Equation:**

`(((((A x 60) + ("1B" % 100)) x 60) + ("1C" % 100)) x 100) + ("1D" % 100)`

**Step by Step:**

(A x 60) = X
X + ("1B" % 100) = Y
(Y x 60) + ("1C" % 100) = Z
(Z x 100) + ("1D" % 100) = start

Note that I use quotations around some of the variables to illustrate that the token is not being multiplied with 1, but instead being appended to the value of 1.  e.g. if `B = 10` then `"1B" = 110`

**Simplified:**

`(((((A x 60) + B) x 60) + C) x 100) + D`

Comment: This is awesome thank you! I've only been writing batch for about a month and I've been having a hard time wrapping my head around the for loop syntax of loops like this.

Comment: Glad to help.  Also read SomethingDark's good explanation as he explains why the `1%%B % 100` are used in relation to batch scripts.